# laravel css & js files are not getting loaded

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

[image: trying to load the CSS files but its not getting loaded when I am running the appliacation]

I am using laravel 5.4 and trying to load the CSS & JS files but its not getting loaded when I am running the application. Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML facade is likely trying to load from your applications public/ directory. You should move your admin/ directory into public/.

Comment: Can i access admin folder without adding it in public (like the way it is in now) ?

Comment: You could use a symlink or perhaps with the base_path() helper, although it's not recommend to expose portions of your application outside of public/ or storage/.